# How can i create custom customer attribute programatically in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, customer-attribute, magento2.3.3, installdata

Here my question is not how to create customer attribute.
I want to know the running flow explanation of this process?
We can create this by below code in custom module.

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Setup;

use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Config;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer;
class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{
private $eavSetupFactory;

public function __construct(EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory, Config $eavConfig)
{
    $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
    $this->eavConfig       = $eavConfig;
}

public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
{
    $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
    $eavSetup->addAttribute(
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY,
        'test_attribute',
        [
            'type'         => 'varchar',
            'label'        => 'test Attribute',
            'input'        => 'text',
            'required'     => false,
            'visible'      => true,
            'user_defined' => true,
            'position'     => 999,
            'system'       => 0,
        ]
    );
    $testAttribute = $this->eavConfig->getAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'test_attribute');

    // more used_in_forms ['adminhtml_checkout','adminhtml_customer','adminhtml_customer_address','customer_account_edit','customer_address_edit','customer_register_address']
    $testAttribute->setData(
        'used_in_forms',
        ['adminhtml_customer']

    );
    $testAttribute->save();
}
}
```

How can i get this customer attribute to show in grid?

If i want to add another attribute is it ok to add that attribute code below this? and run setup:upgrade? how the versions want to mention?
Please explain.

Comment: If data still not update, then remove already created attribute and then, upgrade module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add **'is_used_in_grid' => true**, in your **InstallData.php** for attribute options.

```
<?php 

namespace Vendor\Module\Setup; 

use Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Set as AttributeSet;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\SetFactory as AttributeSetFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory
     */
    private $customerSetupFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\SetFactor
     */
    private $attributeSetFactory;    

    /**
     * Init
     *
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory,
        AttributeSetFactory $attributeSetFactory
    ) {
        $this->customerSetupFactory = $customerSetupFactory;
        $this->attributeSetFactory = $attributeSetFactory;
    }    

    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context) {
         /** @var CustomerSetup $customerSetup */
        $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

        $customerEntity = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getEntityType('customer');
        $attributeSetId = $customerEntity->getDefaultAttributeSetId();

        /** @var $attributeSet AttributeSet */
        $attributeSet = $this->attributeSetFactory->create();
        $attributeGroupId = $attributeSet->getDefaultGroupId($attributeSetId);

        $customerSetup->addAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'test_attribute', [
            'test_attribute' => [
            'label' => 'Test Attribute',
            'type' => 'varchar',
            'input' => 'text',
            'position' => 1000,
            'visible' => true,
            'source' => 'Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Table',
            'required' => false,
            'system' => 0,
            'user_defined' => true,
            'position' => 1000,
            'is_used_in_grid' => true,
            'is_visible_in_grid'    => true,
        ]
        ]);

        $attribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'test_attribute')
        ->addData([
            'attribute_set_id' => $attributeSetId,
            'attribute_group_id' => $attributeGroupId,
            'used_in_forms' => ['adminhtml_customer'],
        ]);

        $attribute->save();
    }
}
```

Do setup upgrade again and check it.

Comment: Thank you. This worked for me.Any idea how to add a dropdown for the same attribute in grid like Gender?

Comment: You can set 'input' => 'select', and set your options in 'option' attribute. Happy coding !! :)